# member/2 in prolog not working as intended

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I am doing a dfs problem using an agent that looks for ships in a grid and picks up the passengers on these ships then drops them off at the station the goal state is all empty ships. In the dfs search I try to prevent the repeated states using the member/2 to check whether a state has already been visited. I've tried debugging the problem as it the output is a bunch of left and right which means the states are repeating but I have no clue why that's happening as I am very new to prolog.

Here I call the the goal It initializes the grid in the predicate s0 and tries to find the path using the path predicate.
`

```
goal(Path) :-
    s0(S0),
    path(S0, Path).
    
% Define the depth-first search algorithm
result(Action, Subpath) :-
    Subpath = result(Action, Subpath).
result(Action, Subpath) :-
    Subpath = s0.

path(S, Path,Visited) :-
    goalCheck(S),
    !.
path(S, Path,Visited) :-
    transition(S, Action, S2),
    \+ member(S2, Visited),
    path(S2, Subpath,[S2|Visited]),
    result(Action, Subpath, Path).


    
path(S, Path) :-
call_with_depth_limit(path(S, Path,S), 10, Path).
```

`Here is the rest of the code, the action predicates check whether an action is possible and the transition predicate return the new state after the action is done.`

```
grid(3,3).
agent_loc(0,1).
ships_loc([[2,2], [1,2]]).
station(1,1).
capacity(1).
onGuard(0).

% define the initial state
s0(S) :-
    agent_loc(X, Y),
    ships_loc(Ships),
    station(SX, SY),
    capacity(Capacity),
    onGuard(OnGuard),
    S = [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard].

% define the goal predicate
goalCheck(S) :-
    S = [[_, _], [], [_, _], _].
% define the possible actions
action(pickup(X, Y),S) :-
    [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard]=S,
    ships_loc(Ships),
    member([X, Y], Ships),
    OnGuard < Capacity .
action(drop,S) :-
    [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard],
    station(X, Y),
    OnGuard > 0 .
action(left,S) :-
    [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard]=S,
    X2 is X - 1,
    X2 >= 0 .
action(right,S) :-
    [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard]=S,
    grid(N, _),
    X2 is X + 1,
    X2 < N .
action(up,S) :-
    [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard]=S,
    grid(_, M),
    Y2 is Y - 1,
    Y2 >= 0,
action(down,S) :-
    [[X, Y], Ships, [SX, SY], Capacity,OnGuard]=S,
    grid(_, M),
    Y2 is Y + 1,
    Y2 < M .

% define the transition function

transition(S, pickup(X, Y), S2) :-
    action(pickup(X, Y),S),
    write("Pickup"),
    [[X, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard] = S,
    select([X, Y], Ships, Ships2), % remove [X, Y] from Ships
    OnGuard2 is OnGuard + 1,
    S2 = [[X, Y], Ships2, Station, Capacity,OnGuard2].
transition(S, drop, S2) :-
    action(drop,S),
    write("drop"),
    [[X, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard] = S,
    OnGuard2 is 0,
    S2 = [[X, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard2].
transition(S, left, S2) :-
    action(left,S),
    write("left"),
    [[X, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard] = S,
    X2 is X - 1,
    X2>=0,
    S2 = [[X2, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard].
transition(S, right, S2) :-
    action(right,S),
    write("right"),
    [[X, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard] = S,
    X2 is X + 1,
    grid(_,M),
    X2<M,
    S2 = [[X2, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard].
transition(S, up, S2) :-
    action(up,S),
    write("up"),
    [[X, Y], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard] = S,
    Y2 is Y - 1,
    Y2>=0,
    S2 = [[X, Y2], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard].
transition(S, down, S2) :-
    action(down,S),
    write("down"),
    [[X, Y],Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard]=S,
    Y2 is Y + 1,
    grid(N,_),
    Y2<N,
    S2 = [[X, Y2], Ships, Station, Capacity,OnGuard].
```

`

I tried running the goal(S) expecting a normal path but it keeps on doing right,left,right,left... indefinitely.

Here is the tracing when it does a left after doing a right and checks if this state has been visited before, it fails, which means this repeating state has not been visited before.

Exit: (17) transition([[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], left, [[0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0]) ? creep

Call: (17) lists:member([[0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], [[[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], [0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0]) ? creep

Fail: (17) lists:member([[0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], [[[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], [0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0]) ? creep

Redo: (16) path([[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], _214, [[[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], [0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0]) ? creep

Comment: `Subpath = result(Action, Subpath).` looks wrong; the definition of `action(left, S)` calculates `X2` but does not use it, that looks wrong for all the actions. "*it keeps on doing right,left,right,left... *" - that's using `write/1` to see the internal behaviours you shouldn't be able to see; it looks left before checking if left is a visited state; then backtracking will undo the variable bindings, but it can't undo `write` so you still see it. I suspect that's misleading and the other problems cause it not to solve. Call `trace` and then trace through it and see what it's doing.

Comment: `path(S, Path,Visited) :- [...] path(S2, Subpath,[S2|Visited])` looks like it's building the path in the wrong place; you don't just want the path created inside the code and then thrown away, you want it to be surfaced as the result of the top level call. e.g. `path(S, [S2|Subpath], Visited) :- [...] path(S2, Subpath, Visited)` (that won't work, but it's closer to the design I'd expect to see)

Comment: I havent tested subpath yet so it could be wrong, but what I did is trace the code and the issue is that when I do a right and then do a left after it doesn't fail and continue using that path where it goes left and right etc am I missing something?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I have added the traced part where I believe there is an issue at the end.

Comment: `Subpath = s0.` is wrong - should be upper-case `S0`, and `S0` is not given a value in that predicate.

Comment: @brebs i found the issue its the brackets around the array when I try to add new states in the visited not sure how to fix yet as you can see here in this visited array  [[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], _214, [[[1, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0], [0, 1], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 1], 1, 0]